# How to pass function to compare items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison, anonymous-function, icomparer

I would like to pass a comparer into a function and not sure if this is possible with Javascript. There is an IComparer concept in C# that does this. Can this be done in Javascript?

```
function someAction (comparer) {
    var newList = [];
        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
            if comparer on item is true then { //psuedo code
                newList.push(item);
            }
        });
}

someAction(item.PropA > 5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`function someAction (comparer) {
    var newList = [];
        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
            if (comparer(item)) {
                newList.push(item);
            }
        });
}
someAction(function (item) { return item.PropA > 5 });`

PS: as @BrokenGlass suggested, you can avoid reinventing the wheel and use the `filter` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function:

```
  if (comparer(item)) { ... }
```

All references to functions in JavaScript are equivalent, so any reference can be used to invoke a function in the same way any other reference can be used. Functions are first-class objects, in other words.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which already exists in JavaScript:

```
var newList = list.filter(function(item) {
  return item.PropA > 5;
});
```

Comment: It should be noted that filter is only available since ECMASCRIPT 5.